# ax 2012 - checking and unchecking of checkbox on form

Tags: axapta, x++

I came across a problem with checking and unchecking the same record on form.
I have a form with list of records, depending on status on record you can see an active/inactive button. Logic for this is included in active method on data source. When i click checkbox first time for some record it is Ok, button acts as required, but when i click this same checkbox second time to uncheck this record, the button does not work ok. For example if a record is checked the button Accept is active, but if a record is unchecked the button Accept should be inactive. I tried to solve this issue also with selectionChanged method but it didn't help. Could you give me some guidance how to handle with this problem?

Below I updated my post with pictures - it is specifically about Confirm button.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you specify the code to check and uncheck the button? and if you select other record of the list form this button work fine? for example first record is checked and second record is not checked.

Comment: public void selectionChanged()
{

    super();
    
    ComplaintMgr_Accept.enabled(Complaints.ComplStatus == ComplStatus::New);
    ReasonOfRejectionDialog.enabled(Complaints.ComplStatus == ComplStatus::New);
    
    ComplaintConfirm.enabled((Complaints.ComplStatus == ComplStatus::Accepted || Complaints.ComplStatus == ComplStatus::Rejected)
        && Complaints.ComplaintConfirmed == Complaints_ComplaintConfirmed.checked(false));


}

Comment: Above my code with logic. If I select other record it works fine - as expected. Problem is when I uncheck sth.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for add you code.

Ok, this is the button `ComplaintConfirm`?? if this is the botton in one part you compare `Complaints.ComplaintConfirmed == Complaints_ComplaintConfirmed.checked(false)`

`Complaints.ComplaintConfirmed` if a enum `NoYesId`?? if a `NoYesId` perhaps here is the error.

Can you try this?

```
ComplaintConfirm.enabled((Complaints.ComplStatus == ComplStatus::Accepted || Complaints.ComplStatus == ComplStatus::Rejected) && Complaints.ComplaintConfirmed == NoYes::No);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answear. It's about button ComplaintConfirm, it's enum type NoYes. I changed code as you suggested but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, really the third image it's ok. because you uncheck a record have `Confirmed = true`. The code is correct and work fine. But also the code should be on the trigger of the **List** that switches between a record and other and here check the same if record it's check or not and enable or disable the button.